# How to change the design of a plot of a function using pgfplots and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wanted to add a sketch of a function using pgfplots and TikZ packages but it did not turn out how I wanted to. I have attached the code I used and what the output was, as well as what I intended. Could anyone kindly point out what I should change? Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed
]
\addplot [
    domain=0:28, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
    ]
    {95*x-153*x^0.83-38};
\addlegendentry{$P(x)=95x-153x^{0.83}-38$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output.png]

What I wanted:
[image: expected.png]

Comment: If you want the x-axis go trough the origin `0` use `axis lines = middle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (main) problem is solved by @Roland comment, so here is some off-topic suggestions about drawings of your diagram:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    xlabel style={anchor=north east, inner xsep=0pt},
    ylabel style={anchor=north east, inner ysep=0pt},
    grid, 
    minor tick num=4,
    grid style={very thin,dashed},
    xmin=-0.5,  
    enlarge y limits=0.1,  
    legend style = {font=\footnotesize},
            ]
\addplot [
    domain=0:27,
    samples=200,
    color=red,
    thick
    ]
    {95*x-153*x^0.83-38};
\legend{$P(x)=95x-153x^{0.83}-38$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Could you also explain what "enlarge y limits=0.1" and "inner xsep=0pt" does?

Comment: `enlarge y limits=0.1` enlarge image in y direction for 10% of size (described on page 331, pgfplots documentation), `inner xsep=0pt` reduce distance between text and left/right node border, to `0pt`, and `inner ysep=0pt` set distance between text and node upper/bottom border to zero (see Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, v 3.1.8b, page 229).